# Make a REST API call to a remote server - Metabase

Tags: metabase

Is there a way to make external API calls whenever we click something on a widget created by Metabase?

Comment: Are you looking to use this for measuring usage (how many people look at dashboard X), or to trigger an external system?

Comment: @jrtapsell To trigger an external system. In my case, it's a dashboard that already has some widgets(not created by metabase). What I would like to do is trigger these widgets/widget by a click on a widget that was created by metabase.
The dashboard that I just mentioned, has a widget created by metabase amongst the native widgets. KInd of like a hybrid dashboard.

Comment: If a table meets the visualisation requirements you can use links to do it, would that help?